# Modify Eigen matrix diagonal

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, diagonal

I have an `Eigen::MatrixXd` and I need to modify the value of the elements in its diagonal. In particular I have another `Eigen::MatrixXd` with one single column and the same number of rows of the first matrix.

I need to subtract to the diagonal of the first matrix the value of the elements of the second matrix.

Example:

```
A
 1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9

B
 1
 1
 1


A'
 0 2 3
 4 4 6
 7 8 8
```

How can I do?

Comment: Subtract some arbitrary diagonal? Or is it always 1's (in other words are you always subtracting the [identity matrix](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a0650b65c6ae6c3d19a138b72a6d68568))

Comment: @CoryKramer arbitrary diagonal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me:

```
A_2=A-B.asDiagonal();
```

Answer (score 8):

The simplest and fastest way to do achieve this is:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A1(3,3), B(3,1), A2;
...
A2 = A1;
A2.diagonal() -= B;
```

of course, better use the `VectorXd` type for vectors (here for `B`), and finally if `B` is constant, then you can use array facilities:

```
A2.diagonal().array() -= 1;
```

Comment: How is this simpler and faster than `A - B.asDiagonal()`?

Comment: Perhaps because it avoids creating B as a diagonal matrix and only has to do A2.rows() calculations rather than A2.size? Although I suppose Eigen is smart enough when it knows B.asDiagonal() is diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < matrix1.rows(); ++i)
    matrix1(i, i) -= matrix2(i, 0);
```

This code iterates over each row of the matrix (`matrix1.rows()`) and subtracts the corresponding value of matrix2 (`matrix2(i, 0)`) from the diagonals in matrix1 (`matrix1(i, i)`).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix manipulation in `Eigen` works very similar to that of arrays. The indexing starts from zero and it is row major. The documentation ([Eigen: The Matrix Class](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html) is well written and may help you to solve future problems.

For your stated problem the solution is given below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
int main()
{
  MatrixXd matA(3,3), matB(3,1);
  matA<<1,2,3,
    4,5,6,
    7,8,9;
  matB<<1,1,1;
  for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
    matA(i,i) -= matB(i);
  std::cout<<matA<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

However, I would use Matrix3d and Vector3d for the first and second matrix, respectively.

Comment: It's probably better to use `matB.rows()` instead of hard-coded number `3`, as done in the answer by @otah007